# How to test closing of x-editable datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, x-editable

I have x-editable datepicker and I'm testing it like this:

```
it('should open edit in place on click', function() {
    var $editable = $date.find('.x-editable');
    $editable.click();
    var $input = $date.find('input');
    expect($editable.hasClass('editable-open')).toBeTruthy();
    expect($editable.hasClass('datepicker-open')).toBeFalsy();
    expect($('.datepicker').length).toEqual(0);
    $input.click();
    expect($editable.hasClass('datepicker-open')).toBeTruthy();
    expect($('.datepicker').length).toEqual(1);
});
```

how can I test closing of datepicker? I've try to call `click()` on different element and also `blur()` on input but the class `datepicker-open` is still present.

Comment: Did you check x-editable [events](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable-events)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found by reading the source code, datepicker add mousedown event so this work:

```
$('body').mousedown()
```